# RecyclerView uses old ViewHolder when data fully changed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that shows "no content" layout before data has been loaded.
After I receive data I do:

```
    mItems.addAll(newItems);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
```

After that everything is fine, except the last element is still "no content" layout. I have checked the behaviour and I know that RecyclerView uses the old layout. The problem is that that I need to use a different layout. And furthermore, why the old layout at last position and not at first as originally it has been?
How do I force RecyclerView to re-create that ViewHolder?

Comment: try using `notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, end-1);` since you have from index 0, until the item count -1, which is the last index. Also remove the +1, from the `notifyItemRangeChanged`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some more reading today I found out that the way to fix this problem is to create another type for view "no content view" in  `getViewType`. So it works like this: first time `onCreateViewHolder` creates viewHolder for empty content. Next time when data is loaded `getViewType` returns different view type and `onCreateViewHolder` creates different view holder.

Answer (score 0):

You call `notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, end)`, now the size of the adapter is 0.
Then you call `notifyItemRangeChanged(0, end)`, but the adapter is empty so what is there to change? This leads to inconsistent state and might be the cause of the undesired behaviour.

Best solution would be to just update the items, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, since, well the entire data set has changed.
Other option is to first call `notifyItemRangeRemoved` with the old size and then `notifyItemRangeInserted` with the new size. Because at this point, you are not *changing* the removed items but adding new ones in.

Comment: I used notifyDataSetChanged() as well, but still no change. The last item is always previous ViewHolder.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for me!
override `getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = viewType`.
override `RecyclerView.Adapter.getItemId(position: Int) = items[position].uniqueId`.
now, when you change data items, they have different ids, but RecyclerView does not know, that old items will go away and keep holders for them, meanwhile new items needed for holders, RecyclerView creates new them and after throw out old holders because of pool max size is 5 by default. change this by `recyclerView.recycledViewPool.setMaxRecycledViews(viewType, x)`, where x is the optimal limit, for example 12 in my case.
to check this, you can set max size 100, change data items time by time and check `recyclerView.recycledViewPool.getRecycledViewCount(viewType)`